# Multiple Text String Modifications in R

Tags: r, text, nlp

I have multiple strings stored in an atomic vector:

```
v <- c("The kat ran up the tree", "The dogg ran up the tree", "The squirrrel run up the tree")
```

I would like to correct the spelling errors:

```
v <- gsub('kat', 'cat', v)
v <- gsub('dogg', 'dog', v)
v <- gsub('squirrel', 'squirrrel', v)
```

However I don't like the repetitive code.  Is there some way to do the equivalent of this:

```
v1 <- c('kat', 'dogg', 'squirrrel')
v2 <- c('cat', 'dog', 'squirrel')

v <- gsub(v1, v2, v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest option is `str_replace_all` and pass a `named` `vector` or `list`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(v, setNames(v2, v1))
```

-output

```
#[1] "The cat ran up the tree"     
#[2] "The dog ran up the tree"  
#[3]    "The squirrel run up the tree"
```